# Malayalam characters with dot above or below

Tags: xetex, indic

[image: This is the kind of characters needed.]There is a need in Malayalam to typeset musical notations that have dots above or below a letter denoting the note. I was wondering if there is a way in XeLaTeX by which the dot can be added at the required place, without creating a font that has such characters, or if it is essential to build a font that has such characters. If a special font is needed, it will have to be built. I find that this is a problem in all typesetting applications from Pagemaker to InDesign, and in word processors too.

Comment: Could you please add a picture of what you mean?

Comment: Generally, TeX produce most of the accent characters by coding not through the font, e.g., `\'{}, \dot{}, \"{}`, etc. Can you please provide a screenshot or more clearance of your requirement?...

Comment: I know how to add accents with Latin characters, but that doesn't seem to work with Malayalam. I feel that a font that has such accented characters is needed, as in Latin also, that is what I find. I can't seem to find a way to add an image here, so I have added it in the question.

Comment: Please see that upvoting and accepting the most helpful answer here is the usual way to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 1):

The following macros works well in many Unicode Malayalam fonts like
Rachana, Gayathri, Manjari.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\mal{\fontspec[Script=Malayalam]{Rachana}} 
\newcommand*{\Largerdot}{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.1}{.}}}
\newcommand{\dotu}[1]{$\stackrel{\Largerdot}{\mbox{{#1}}}$}  %% to get the tarastahyi dots
\newcommand{\dotd}[1]{$\stackrel{\mbox{{#1}}}{\Largerdot}$}  %% to get the tarastahyi dots
\begin{document}

\dotu{{\mal സ}} \dotu{{\mal രി  }} \dotu{{\mal ഗ }} \dotu{{\mal മ   }} \dotu{{\mal പ  }} \dotu{{\mal ധ   }} \dotu{{\mal നി }}  ---the note ``{\mal   സ രി ഗ മ പ ധ നി }" in \textsl{tāra sthāyi}

\dotd{{\mal സ}} \dotd{{\mal രി  }} \dotd{{\mal ഗ }} \dotd{{\mal മ }} \dotd{{\mal പ  }} \dotd{{\mal ധ   }} \dotd{{\mal നി }} --- the note ``{\mal  സ രി ഗ മ പ ധ നി }" in  \textsl{mandra sthāyi}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: The macro \dotu {{  }} is for dot above (tara sthayi)  and \dotd{{ }}  is for dot below (mandra sthayi) a character.  For some reason, I need two flower brackets for each

Comment: This is very useful and solves a big problem that DTP operators have been facing while typesetting music books in Malayalam. Thank you, Narayanaswami. However, it is interesting to see that the dotu and dotd commands require two braces each. Wonder if someone knowledgeable could explain why. It doesn't work with single braces.

Comment: The two commands \dotu, \dotd work fine  with a single bracket, and they do no need  double braces.  Just type \dotu{സ}, \dotd{സ}, respectively  and the dots are correctly places above, below the character "സ".